# Prestashop backend module diplay error

Tags: php, prestashop

On Prestashop 1.6 admin when i am trying to login i am getting this error

```
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module smarty_internal_templatebase:
Uncaught --> Smarty: Invalid compiled template for 'controllers/modules/page.tpl' <-- thrown
```

can any body help this?
On the admin panel when i am clicking on module i am getting this message. Yesterday i installed some customized modules into my prestashop project.

Comment: I am not getting it.. please explain so that I can understand and answer the question.

Comment: Can you post the page.tpl file as well as the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissons of the folder cache/smarty/compile

must be 755 or 777 for all folders and subfolders

Comment: Could you please explain the rationale behind that suggestion?